# log4j syslogappender stack trace output not on the same line

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, log4j, rsyslog

I am trying to get centralised logging working with log4j and rsyslog.

**What I have so far**

Solr running inside tomcat6 on RHEL6, using  the following log4j and sl4j libs

```
# lsof -u tomcat | grep log4j
java    14503 tomcat  mem    REG              253,0      9711    10208 /usr/share/java/tomcat6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
java    14503 tomcat  mem    REG              253,0    481535    10209 /usr/share/java/tomcat6/log4j-1.2.16.jar
java    14503 tomcat  mem    REG              253,0    378088  1065276 /usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.14.jar
java    14503 tomcat   20r   REG              253,0    378088  1065276 /usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.14.jar
java    14503 tomcat   21r   REG              253,0    481535    10209 /usr/share/java/tomcat6/log4j-1.2.16.jar
java    14503 tomcat   35r   REG              253,0      9711    10208 /usr/share/java/tomcat6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
#
```

Solr is using the following log4j.properties file (via -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/solr/lib/log4j.properties)

```
#  Logging level
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE, SYSLOG

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x \u2013 %m%n

#- size rotation with log cleanup.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=4MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=9

#- File to log to and log format
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/tomcat6/solr.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}; %C; %m\n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=WARN

# set to INFO to enable infostream log messages
log4j.logger.org.apache.solr.update.LoggingInfoStream=OFF

#- Local syslog server
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=LOCAL1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=${sysloghostname} %-4r [%t] java %-5p %c %x %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
```

On the same server I have rsyslog running and accepting log messages from log4j.

```
# rpmquery -a | grep syslog
rsyslog-5.8.10-7.el6_4.x86_64
#
```

rsyslog config

```
# #### MODULES ####
$MaxMessageSize 32k
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad imfile   # provides file monitoring support
#
$ModLoad imudp.so
$UDPServerRun 514
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
# #### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
# # Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down

$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 0 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # chain and server are verified
#local1.*;*.* @@(o)XXXXXXXX:5544
local1.*                                                /var/log/remote.log
# # The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
# # Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
# # Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
# # Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *
# # Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
# # Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

I am catching local1 messages from Solr's logj4 and redirecting them to /var/log/remote.log
Everything works as expected. Sample INFO message

```
Oct 31 13:57:08 hostname.here 3431839 [http-8080-10] java INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={indent=true&q=*:*&wt=json&rows=1} hits=42917 status=0 QTime=1
```

And stack traces are on the same line as the ERROR message

```
Oct 31 12:27:17 hostname.here 157666248 [http-8080-7] java ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field *#012#011at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1223)#012... Cut for brevity....#011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)#012
```

Note #012 as line ending and #011 tab.

Using this setup I can ship the logs to remote rsyslog server over TCP and pipe them into fluentd/elaticsearch/kibana etc... everything works as expected.

**The problem** 
I am now trying to get another webapp running inside the same tomcat container to log as above, everything works as expected apart from stack traces, each line of a stack trace ends up on a separate line (separate syslog message)

```
Oct 31 12:54:47  hostname.here 4909 [main] java ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  could not get database metadata
Oct 31 12:54:47 hostname.here org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
Oct 31 12:54:47 hostname.here 
Oct 31 12:54:47 hostname.here The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

The webapp ships with it's own log4j libs and log4j.xml config. Libs are of the same version as those used by solr.

log4j.xml file for this app

```
 <appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
                <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost" />
                <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL1" />
                <param name="Header" value="false" />
                <property name="facilityPrinting" value="false"/>
                <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern"
                      value="%-4r [%t] java %-5p %c %x %m%n"/>
                </layout>
                </appender>
```

I would like to see stack traces from the new application to appear on the same line just like with Solr.

Does anyone know if this is a log4j config issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on something similar lately (in fact, I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117329/hostname-value-is-unknown-in-rsyslog) open presently you may be able to help with).

This is probably not a very good answer, but it's more information than I can fit in a comment so here you go (I hope some of it is new to you).  The rsyslog [imfile](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imfile.html) rsyslog documentation has this section:

> ReadMode [mode]
>
> This mode should defined when having multiline messages. The value can range from 0-2 and determines the multiline detection method.
>   0 (default) - line based (Each line is a new message)
>   1 - paragraph (There is a blank line between log messages)
>   2 - indented (New log messages start at the beginning of a line. If a line starts with a space it is part of the log message before it)

The [imudp](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imudp.html) rsyslog docs have no such configuration option.  My guess is that the UDP input module doesn't support multiline logging.  Thus, each line of the stack trace is sent out as a separate log entry.

Do you have any configuration files in /etc/rsyslog.d?  There may be more information in there.

Comment: Thanks for that. I gave up trying to get rsyslog working and went with http://fluentd.org/ . We are shipping Java application logs running inside Tomcat and it has been working well so far with a few minor glitches. It's far more flexible than rsyslog. If you are interested I can share our configuration.

Comment: I hadn't heard of fluentd.  That's clever.  So, you make your stack trace a collection and then serialize it on 1 line of json?  How's your experience using elastic search with your fluentd log entries?  Yeah, I'd like to get an idea of the configuration you settled on.  Thanks Andrey.

Comment: I customised log4j layout to include app name and hostname (picked up from java system property set on Tomcat statup with -D).Log files are then read by fluentd http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail plugin and sent to another fluentd server that listens with http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_forward plugin. This server then stores entries in Elastic with https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch .We then have http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/ reading from Elastic. Stacktraces are caught with regexp (see "format" in http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail).